# How to expand a DIV when menu is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cigifeti/1/edit)

What happens is when you click on Menu, it open to display contents inside. How can I edit the JQuery so when the menu is open the inside div and the menu div is expanded and on menu close the inside div and menu is shrunk to the initial size?

Original as shown in the JSBIN link:

[image]

When the the user clicks on MENU it should expand like this:

[image]

When the user clicks again on the MENU, the DIV should go back to the original side.

Can someone help me achieve that?

Comment: so basically you don't want the menu flip effect?

Comment: No the menu effect is good except when I click on menu I want it to expand like in the right side of the picture.

Comment: Like this http://jsbin.com/cigifeti/10/edit

Comment: just add a margin style to .open check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JQuery `slideToggle()` for this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#menu').click(function(){ //where menu is the id of your menu item
   $('#content').slideToggle(); // where content is the id of your content div
  });
});
```

initially you need to hide the div using css `display:none` or JQuery methods such as `hide()`, `slideUp()` etc..

**UPDATE:** working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/5CK93/)

change the following:

```
.cover { //removed the absolute positioning which is hiding the content div
color: white;
text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
font-size: 3em;
width: 200px;
height:70px;
background: linear-gradient(#30CCFC, #2CC5EF);
text-align:center;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px #54AED0;
cursor: pointer;
transform-style: preserve-3d; 
transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
transform-origin: bottom center; 
}

.tweet{
display:none; //initially hide the element
}
```

add this script:

```
$(function () {
  $('.cover').on('click', function(){
  $('.tweet').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

and see it work.

*updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/5CK93/2/)*

Comment: Everything is working as it should. I want the div to EXPAND to show the contents inside.

Comment: the JSBIN saves automatically. Your fiddle is working, except I still want the MENU to flip like in mine :)

Comment: If you click on my MENU it flips in my JSBIN so I would like to keep the same effect but slide down as well like yours.

Comment: @SiKni8 i beleive you are refering to the highlight of menu button, which is the only effect i can see in bin..  check this http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/5CK93/2/

Comment: @SiKni8 would be nice if you accept the answer if it worked.. :)

Comment: Of course. I wasn't in the page so I couldn't accept. Question though, how do I make the entire DIV float so it doesn't push down on other DIVS and is on it's own?

Answer (score 1):

Just include it in your html with `hidden="true"` and when you need to show it use this

```
$('your-div-id').show();
```

Comment: Everything is working as it should. I want the div to EXPAND to show the contents inside.

Answer (score 1):

Put two divs like this:

```
<div id="content">Stuff stuff stuff</div>
<br />
<div id="menu">MENU</div>
```

the top one is the one that will be expanded, as in your image. The bottom one is the button. Now, the jQuery is fairly simple:

```
$("#content").height( 0 );
$("#menu").click(function(){
    $("#content).height( 100 );
});
```

If you want the user to click, menu open, click again and it closes:

```
var open = false;
$("#content").height( 0 );
$("#menu").click(function(){
    if (open == false){
        $("#content").height( 100 );
        open = true;
    } else {
        $("#content").height( 0 );
        open = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XX6JB/). Just added a margin style to div. is this what you are looking for?

```
.open {
 margin-top : 80px;
 transform: rotateX(-180deg);
 box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3),
 inset 0 0 1px 1px #54AED0;
 background: linear-gradient(#33CEFE, #38D6FD);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change your code like this,

```
 $(function () {
    $('.cover').on('click', function(){
        if ($(this).css("position") == "absolute")
            $(this).css("position", "relative");
         else
            $(this).css("position", "absolute");
    });
 });
```